# WordPress plugin content after the_content using add_filter()

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to add `my_custom_function` after `the_content` in WordPress using

```
add_filter ('the_content', 'my_custom_function');
add_action ('the_content', 'my_custom_function'); // I tried both
```

My `my_custom_function` function is like this

```
function my_custom_function($content) {
    if(is_single()) {
        $content .= "this is custom function content";
        $content .= my_another_custom_function();
        $content .= "this is custom function content";
    }

return $content;
}
```

My problem is this code is appending `my_another_custom_function()` **before** `the_content` but I want it **after** the content.

The other 2 lines given in the code `$content .= "this is custom function content";` is for testing and these are appearing **after** `the_content`

Can someone please give me any idea about how to fix it and what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most possible reason is that my_another_custom_function() echoes the output instead of just returning it.

Comment: My another_custom_function is like this 
`function m_a_c_f{
  echo '<ol>';
  foreach ( $result as $result ){
   echo '<li>';
   echo $result->title;
   echo '</li>';
 }
  echo '</ol>';
}` 

Can you please tell me how to return this not echo, and I also have to use this function somewhere else [manually]. How can I use it there after that?